# Download Files from TFS based on theirs labes using powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

How can i find and download files from tfs based on their labels using powershell.
i found a code that downloads the latest version, but i want a specific labeled version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call tf command in the powershell script to do this, the steps required to pull a label from TFS e as follows:

1. Specify the following as input parameters:   Disk location where
   label is pulled (source code directory)   TFS work space and folder
   from which code is pulled   Label name associated with TS work space
   and folder
2. Delete existing code from the source code directory
3. Create the source code directory
4. Change the current-working directory to the source code directory
   The reason for this is outlined in: "Build Automation: Getting
   multiple labels from TFS using TF GET (without deleting the files associated with the previous TF GET)" (optional)
5. Delete the TFS work space if it exists a.k.a. tf workspace /delete
6. Create the TFS work space a.k.a. tf workspace /new
7. Map the source code folder to the collection folder and associate
   this mapping with the work space a.k.a. tf workfold /map
8. Get the label from TFS a.k.a. `tf get /version:L<label name>
   /noprompt`

Detail code please refer this blog: [How to Correctly pull labels from TFS using PowerShell](http://www.softwarepronto.com/2013/11/build-automation-how-to-correctly-pull.html)

Another way is using TFS API, instead of directly get latest, you could use a **[VersionSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versionspec(v=vs.120).aspx)** to specify which version you want. Such as a DateVersionSpec, a ChangeVersionSet or a LabelVersionSet. Detail code please refer [How to use the TFS API to retrieve a historical version of your project](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.sg/2011/05/how-to-use-tfs-api-to-retrieve.html), you could - involve [TFS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/architecture/extend-vs-for-alm) in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed responce ,but, am using dllsin the donwload script, to get the latest version i pass "[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::latest" as a parameter to GetItems method, how to do it for a Label (Version)

Comment: @DouraidTLILI There is a [LabelVersionSpec Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.labelversionspec(v=vs.120).aspx), haven't tried, but should be something like this  ` "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelVersionSpec"   -argumentList $sTFSlabel` a string of label name. You could take a look at this blog, even though it's using `vcs.DownloadFile`  method: http://www.cnblogs.com/Henry1225/archive/2012/05/07/2487503.html